Debugging a component at Design-time with Delphi 12 doesn't work
I can't debug another instance of Delphi anymore.
Up to Delphi 11, I can build my packages in debug, open my component .pas file and put a breakpoint in the first line of the Create procedure, then go to Run, Set parameter to c:\program files (x86)....\bds.exe and run it. When the second Delphi opens, I can see my breakpoints in blue, and if I drop my component on a form then the process hits my breakpoint in the first delphi.
Well, it worked from D3 up to D11, but we updated to D12 and that does not work anymore. I saw posts that in some version D10x or D11x it was broken, but fixed in D11.4.
I am wondering if there is something I can do, like a workaround for the moment?
Steps:

Open Delphi
Open your Package of component
Build in Debug mode and set a breakpoint at first line of Create
Go to Run and set
Host Application to C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\bin\bds.exe and Parameter I put -pDelphi
Rebuild (maybe not necessary)
Click Run. Another instance of Delphi should open
Once it’s open, Click New → VCL application
Once the form is displayed,  find your component and drop it on the form.
Go back to the first Delphi. You will not see any blue dot that says it’s loaded, and your breakpoints won’t be hit.

I tried in Delphi 12, 12 patch, and delphi 12.2.

Sounds like a bug that you should report to Embarcadero directly.

Already did in May.. since nothing

What is the bug ticket number?

Is "Click Run." supposed to be "Click Run With Debugging"?

https://embt.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/1/RSS-1044 Friday they said they will investigate., I'll let you know here once this is fixed

I discovered this bug in April/24. Reported to Embarcadero case#: 01121887. This is the response I received from Christopher Moeller of Embarcadero: 'There are several reports in our bug portal which are tracking this defect, but the reports (RS-120676/RSP-43537) appear to be most frequently referenced. I would recommend that you continue using your working 11.3 to allow debugging to proceed until the issue is formally addressed. That said, the product managers have been notified of the severity of this issue and the impact on our customers so they can reprioritize.'

On May 31/24 Marco Cantu added a the following comment to RSP-43537 'to workaround this bug: open Tools | Options | Debugger | Embarcadero Debuggers | Debug symbol search path, enter: $(BDSLIB)$(PLATFORM)\Debug'. But this workaround did not work for me.

One issue I found is the IDE simply stops and puts a breakpoint in the Disassembly Window but does not surface said window. Surface the Disassembly window manually with Ctrl-Alt-D and remove erstwhile breakpoint and advance. My test shows a license issue which may be a bad internet connection on my machine.
Another issue 12.1 hung on my custom control's MyCustomControl.dcr icon when compiling it's library. Now IDE show its icon on rail and in form designer when used. :)  It was lost in 10's and 11's. This happened a month into using 12.1 and not obvious.
It's easier to build custom components in runtime and set the parent container then.
